# Configure Kestrel using hosting.json and appsettings.json in dotnet core v2

Tags: c#, json, database, ubuntu

I need to setup a project in dotnet core on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server with a database connected to it. I followed this tutorial and I managed it to get it online on a certain domain name/ip.

Tutorial I used:
https://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNETCoreWebsiteToACheapLinuxVMHost.aspx

At this point, my plain, clean mvc-project is running. However, I need to make a connection with a database. I have one running on a different server (I have the correct credentials). But I have a problem with the hosting .json file. It seems to conflict with the regular appsettings.json file.

#### hosting.json

```
{
    "server.urls": "http://localhost:5123"
}
```

#### Program.cs v1 (works online but without db connection)

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
    .Build();

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

#### Program.cs v2 (works offline with db, not online)

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     BuildWebHost(args).Run();
 }

 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .UseStartup<Startup>()
         .Build();
```

#### appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "correctdb": "Server=correctip;Database=correctdb;Uid=SA;Pwd=correctpass",
    "providerName": "Sql.Data.SqlClient"
  }
}
```

This is my error msg: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLRHT.png)
My main issue, is that I have a feeling it's conflicting with the Kestrel-settings in dotnet core v2 using that hosting.json like the tutorial says.

Whenever I use Program.cs v2 is only runs offline with database connection. Whenever I use Program.cs v1 it runs online, but without the connection.

Is there another way to configure Kestrel without using the hosting.json? 
Help is much appreciated.

#### edit 1

```
 var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
    .Build();
```

#### edit 2

```
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader, JsonLoadSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Load(JsonReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.Parse(Stream input)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at webapp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/ubuntu/webapp/Program.cs:line 30
```

#### edit 3

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
 {
      Configuration = configuration;
 }

 public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

 // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
     services.AddDbContext<WebappContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("correctdb")));
     services.AddMvc();
 }
```

#### edit 4

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you uploaded the appsettings.json?

Also, the v1 isn't loading the appsettings.json file, what the `CreateDefaultBuilder` does is load the standard things, so it will load appsettings.json when it exists.

Comment: I just checked, it's the exact same one as in my post. I uploaded it again, dotnet published it again, copied content to /var/project directory and reloaded my nginx. Error still occurs

Comment: Have you tried adding `AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);` below the first `AddJsonFile` to the v1?

Comment: I tried (see edit 1), but no success. Error keeps occuring.

Comment: Could you show how you are trying to access to the connection string?

Comment: The name of the connection (according to the provided appsettings.json content) is `ICTLabDatabase` but you are using `correctdb` is it that way on the actual Program.cs or just on example?

Comment: That was a typo, it is just for example purposes - I've changed it ;)

Comment: Only other thing I could think of is, maybe on the server online, it's either unable to find or access the appsettings.json file, try setting it as non-optional, it should throw an exception if that's the case

Comment: Unfortunately, the error keeps showing up. Even when I put the optional boolean to false for appsettings.json. Maybe the format of the AddDbContext()-function could be the issue?

Comment: If after changing the `optional` argument to false for the `appsettings.json` still getting the exact same exception as shown on the picture, it means `GetConnectionString` can't find a connection string with the name you are giving to it (`correctdb`) ... Other than make sure it's the exact same file (maybe do a `cat....` and compare both files to confirm that the file uploaded correctly) can't think of anything else

Comment: I managed to get it working. I thought you'd might wanna to know the solution :)